# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | FileUploadResult'

Tags: angular, file-upload, promise, ionic3

I developed a provider to manage upload/download of pictures in my Ionic3 app. This works well but now I would like to get the data returned by the promise that uploaded the file to the server. I could see the content I expected if I use the *alert* function but I could not access to the JSON content as my text editor reports me this error:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | FileUploadResult'
```

[image]

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

My code in my_page.ts:

```
uploadImage(newFileName) {
    this.attCtrl.uploadAttachment({ file: newFileName })
                .then((response) => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response)); // The JSON appears exactly like I expected
                    alert(response.data); // => Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | FileUploadResult'
                })
                .catch((err)=> {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                })

    ;
}
```

then, my code in the provider:

```
public uploadAttachment(obj) {

    let targetPath = this.pathForImage(obj.file);
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        ...
    };

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    return fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
        return data;
    }, err => {
        this.loading.dismissAll();
    });
}
```

Comment: change success handler definition to `.then((response: any) => {`

Comment: Thanks, it is better, I have no more the error in my text editor. Nevertheless, I cannot not access to response.data. alert(response.data) returns undefined although I can clearly see content of data with the alert(response).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to handle the response from FileUpload. First the interface FileUploadResult should be imported:

```
import { FileUploadResult } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
```

Then, set this interface *FileUploadResult* to the response, and parse the response:

```
uploadImage(newFileName) {
    this.attCtrl.uploadAttachment({ file: newFileName, page: 'wo', target_id: this.wo.wo_id })
                .then((r: FileUploadResult) => {
                    let obj = JSON.parse(r.response);
                    // Then obj can be handled
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    alert(err);
                });
}
```